# Is it possible to insert javascript charts into a JavaFX application

Tags: javascript, java, highcharts, javafx

I would like to have a good looking chart in my JavaFX application.
There is a lot of data to put in the chart and with the basic LineChart from JavaFX i can't zoom in to hava a more accurate view.
So i found highcharts.com which use javascript, but I would like to know if it's possible to use it in a JavaFX application directly.

Thanks

Comment: I thought JavaFX was a dead technology.  Flash is certainly dead.  I wonder why you wouldn't want to do HTML5, CSS3, JavaScript and jQuery for UI?  d3.js will certainly chart anything you need.

Comment: @duffymo I'm not sure where you get the idea JavaFX is a "dead technology". A new version was released alongside Java 8 is now included in the standard JDK from Oracle, and updates are planned for Java 9. And you're not really comparing like to like: JavaFX is a "thick-client" (i.e. standalone desktop) technology; the technologies you list are thin-client technologies that display inside a browser.

Comment: Like Flash....dead technology.  Java 8 ships with applets, too.

Comment: So if you want to write a desktop app in Java, you use what? Swing (which has been in maintenance-only mode for how long now)?  Or are you arguing that desktop applications in Java are a dead technology?

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating the chart in HTML and Javascript, and then displaying the resulting page in a JavaFX [`WebView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html). `WebView` uses a webkit driven engine, so it should work with any reasonable html/javascript that runs in webkit browsers, though as with any web engine technology there are some exceptions.

I would try that and post a more specific question if you can't get things to work.